# How to "maximze" window size but still within dock and menu bar?

Tags: window-manager

Let's say I'm running an app. If the green button is clicked, the app will be set into fullscreen mode. I don't want that.

Instead I want it to be "semi maximized" like this, that is not overflowing the menu bar (on top) and dock (on bottom). Of course, I have to drag/resize the window manually. Is there a shortcut to do this?

I'm on Monterey, BTW.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>  green dot & also the double-click title bar both  *kind of* maximise, but it won't always fill the entire screen. Depending on the document type, it may just fill top to bottom, but not full width.

To make it fill the entire screen,  <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>  double click any window corner, once the cursor turns into a double arrow. This will stop short of the Dock, if you have it always visible, otherwise fill the whole screen.

[image]

<kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>  double-click is actually quite flexible. If you use it on one edge of a window it will expand to fit, but just in that direction, horizontal or vertical.
If you  <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>  drag by either an edge or a corner, opposite sides or the entire window will resize equally.

Comment: Ah learn a new thing today: Opt + green dot. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Actually probably the easiest thing to do would be to double-click a window's title bar to maximize the window.  You can set this in your System Preferences.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Hold the <kbd>⌥Option</kbd> key while clicking the green button. That will "zoom" the window instead of making it full screen. Zoom is intended to make a window as large as it needs to be to display its contents without scrolling.

For many applications, zooming is effectively the same as maximising.